# Merge Objects from two arrays based on user id keeping all properties from each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm looping through a bunch of arrays containing different objects with different properties and adding these to a main array. I'm trying to merge the objects from the looped array to the main array where each object has a matching userid, however if there is no matching userid from the looped array I want to simply add the object to the main array, and if there is no matching userid in the main array, then I simply want to keep it within the main array. For example:

```
let mainArr = [];

iteration 1 = [
  { userid: 'a',
    year: 2017
  },
  { userid: 'b',
    year: 2019
  },
  { userid: 'c',
    year: 2019
  }
]

iteration 2 = [
  { userid: 'a',
    amount: 100
  },
  { userid: 'd',
    amount: 200
  },
  { userid: 'c',
    amount: 300
  }
]

iteration 3 = [
  { userid: 'a',
    length: 50
  },
  { userid: 'd',
    length: 20
  },
  { userid: 'e',
    length: 10
  }
]
```

This should result in the following

```
mainArr = [
  { userid: 'a',
    year: 2017,
    amount: 100,
    length: 50
  },
  { userid: 'b',
    year: 2019
  },
  { userid: 'c',
    year: 2019,
    amount: 300
  },
  { userid: 'd',
    amount: 200,
    length: 20
  },
  { userid: 'e',
    length: 10
  }
]
```

So far when I have attempted this with the below, but if the userid isn't found, it is removed from the mainArr

```
const mergeById = (a1, a2) =>
a1.map(itm => ({ ...a2.find((item) => (item.user_id === itm.user_id) && item), ...itm }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
const merger = (result, arrays) => {
  arrays.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(element => {
      const index = result.findIndex(e => e.userid === element.userid)
      if (index !== -1) {
        result[index] = { ...result[index], ...element }
      } else {
        result.push(element)
      }
    })
  })
  return result
}

merger(mainArr, [iteration1, iteration2, iteration3])
```

It's a naive implementation, but it should helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping over one arrays values, so the items missing in it and in the second array will be lost.

Here is how I will modify your mergeArr function :

- Starts with having an array with all the elements.
- It uses `reduce()` and `findIndex()`

```js
let mainArr = [];

let a1 = [
  { userid: 'a',
    year: 2017
  },
  { userid: 'b',
    year: 2019
  },
  { userid: 'c',
    year: 2019
  }
]

let a2 = [
  { userid: 'a',
    amount: 100
  },
  { userid: 'd',
    amount: 200
  },
  { userid: 'c',
    amount: 300
  }
]

let a3 = [
  { userid: 'a',
    length: 50
  },
  { userid: 'd',
    length: 20
  },
  { userid: 'e',
    length: 10
  }
]

const mergeById = (a1, a2) => {
let newArr = [...a1,...a2];
let returnArr = newArr.reduce((acc,a) => {
let index = acc.findIndex(x => x.userid === a.userid);
if(index > -1){
acc[index] = {...acc[index],...a};
}
else acc.push(a);
return acc;
},[]);
return returnArr;
}
let newArr1 = mergeById(a1,a2);
let newArr2 = mergeById(newArr1,a3);
console.log(newArr2);
```